# How to make sure that page zoom level is 100%

Tags: javascript

I want to be sure that the user hasn't zoomed the page on my web app. So I want to alert (in chrome) the user if he/she zoom the page and keep alerting till the user zooms back to 100%.

Here is the code I've tried with no success. it keeps alerting even if we zoom back to 100%.

**Note:** in the fullscreen mode, we get `0.9908854166666666` as zoom level and in exit we get `1` for 100% zoom in chrome.

```js
let zoom;

window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
   
   zoom = window.outerWidth / window.document.documentElement.clientWidth; // detect page zoom
   //console.log(zoom);

      while(!(zoom <= 1 && zoom > 0.99)){
               
          alert('Please do not Zoom the page to continue...');
           zoom = window.outerWidth / window.document.documentElement.clientWidth;
           console.log(zoom);
           
      }
   
   
});
```

Comment: Why do you want this? It seems very unfriendly to people whose sight is impaired, for example.

Comment: Whilst I don't have an answer, not allowing a user to zoom your page is very bad for accessibility

Comment: Why??? Very bad UX.

Comment: Maybe they do not use this restriction every time Darren, Elias. What if they want to use this function just before getting a screenshot, and they do not want to waste extra paper(s), or wants to sure the screen should be fitted a certain sized of paper, or only on one [MY] specific page?

Comment: "It seems very unfriendly to people whose sight is impaired" How do you know  jonrsharpe that my user's sight is impaired?

Comment: accessibility of what Darren Sweeney?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is not a good practice for accessibility, however, I have created a solution.
But first, your function doesn't keep alerting on 100% because the condition isn't right. in fact, it does that because this condition will always return true hence an infinite loop. so even if the user could zoom out it will keep looping. Moreover, you should also be giving the user some time to zoom out.
That said, you should instead write an `if condition` that sets an `interval` in which the interval alerts the user until the user zooms out/in to 100%

```js
let zoom;

let notificationInterval;
let attempt = 0;

function notifyUser() {
    alert('Please do not Zoom the page to continue...');
}

window.addEventListener("resize", function () {

    zoom = window.outerWidth / window.document.documentElement.clientWidth; // detect page zoom
    //console.log(zoom);

    if (!(zoom <= 1 && zoom > 0.99)) {
        attempt++;
        zoom = window.outerWidth / window.document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        if (attempt == 1) {
            alert('Please do not Zoom the page to continue...');
            notificationInterval = setInterval(notifyUser, 3000)
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log("fixed zoom");
        clearInterval(notificationInterval);
        attempt = 0;
    }
});
```